# While moving back from a certain page in react native, the elements from the back page does not load. Could you please guide a soulution

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation

This is my home page: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2172z.jpg)
This a different page from where if I move back to home [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pRqj.jpg)
I am having this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSz3x.jpg)

I have tried multiple methods to but none of them really helped. Could you please tell me why and care to provide me a solution. Thank you!

Here is code of Home screen:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import {Modal, Image, TouchableOpacity, TouchableNativeFeedback, ImageBackground, SafeAreaView, BackHandler, Text, View, Animated, StatusBar, ScrollView, Alert, Linking, Dimensions, Pressable} from "react-native";
import FooterTabs from "../component/Nav/FooterTabs"
import GlobalPlaylistCarousel from '../component/homeModules/GlobalPlaylistCarousel'
const {width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight} = Dimensions.get('window');
import YoutubePlayer from "react-native-youtube-iframe";
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import { GoogleSignin } from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'
import TopShows from "../component/HomeModule/TopShowsModule";
import { api, hindiApi } from "../component/HomeModule/Api";
import HindiTopShows from "../component/HomeModule/HindiTopShows";

const youtubeUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/c/BloomTelly/videos";
const facebook = "https://www.facebook.com/bloomtelly";
const instagram = "https://www.instagram.com/bloomtelly/?hl=en";
const subscribe = "https://www.youtube.com/c/BloomTelly?sub_confirmation=1";

const Home = () => {
  const [shows, setShows] = useState('English')
  useEffect(()=>{
    AsyncStorage.getItem('language').then((v)=>setShows(v))
  },[])
  const HeaderHeight = screenHeight*0.075
  const scrollY = new Animated.Value(0)
    const diffClampScrollY = Animated.diffClamp(scrollY, 0, HeaderHeight+StatusBar.currentHeight)
    const footerY = diffClampScrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange:[0, HeaderHeight],
      outputRange: [0, HeaderHeight]
    })
    const headerY = diffClampScrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange:[0, HeaderHeight],
      outputRange: [0, -HeaderHeight]
    })
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const [modalvisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
    const [logModel, setlogModel] = useState(false)
    const [openRoot, setOpenroot] = useState(false)

    const handleSignout = async() => {
      if(auth().currentUser.providerData.map((i)=>i.providerId) == 'google.com'){
        await GoogleSignin.revokeAccess()
        await auth().signOut().then(()=> {
          navigation.replace('Signin')
        }).catch (e=>console.log(e))
      }
      else{
        await auth().signOut().then(()=>{
          navigation.replace('Signin')
        }).catch (e=>console.log(e))
      }
    }
    const setShowColorEnglish = () => {
      if(shows == 'English'){
        return '#606c38'
      } else {
        return 'rgba(96, 108, 56, 0.5)'
      }
    }
    const setShowColorHindi = () => {
      if(shows == 'Hindi'){
        return '#606c38'
      } else {
        return 'rgba(96, 108, 56, 0.5)'
      }
    }

    return (
        <>
        <Modal
            animationType="slide"
            transparent={true}
            visible={modalvisible}
            onRequestClose={()=>{
            setModalVisible(!modalvisible)
            }}
        >
            <View style={{width:"100%", height: "100%", top:0, backgroundColor: 'rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.9)', }}>
                <Pressable onPress={()=> { return setModalVisible(false)}}  style={{width:"100%", alignItems:"center",height:"35%"}}>
                </Pressable>
                <View style={{ zIndex:1000, elevation:1000}}>
                    <YoutubePlayer
                        height={220}
                        width={screenWidth}
                        play={true}
                        videoId={global.foo}
                        style={{zIndex:1000, elevation:1000, position:"absolute"}}
                    />
                </View>
                <Pressable onPress={()=> { return setModalVisible(false)}} style={{ width:"100%", height:"60%"}}></Pressable>
            </View>
        </Modal>
        <ImageBackground source={require('../assets/bg.png')}  style={{width:"100%", height: "100%",
            position: "absolute", top:0, left:0, right: 0, bottom:0,
        }}/>
        <SafeAreaView>
        <Animated.View style={{backgroundColor:"'rgba(58, 58, 58, 0.3)'", width:screenWidth, height:screenHeight*0.07, flex:1, flexDirection:"row", justifyContent:"space-between", position:"absolute", zIndex:1000, elevation:1000, transform:[{translateY:headerY}] }}>
            <Pressable onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('Test')} style={{width:screenWidth/2, height:screenHeight*0.07,  alignItems:"flex-start", justifyContent:"center"}}>
              <Image source={require('../assets/logo.png')} style={{height:screenHeight*0.04, width:screenWidth*0.2, marginLeft:10}}/>
            </Pressable>
          </Animated.View>
         <Animated.ScrollView
         bounces={false}
         scrollEventThrottle={16}
         style={{paddingTop:HeaderHeight*0.1}}
           onScroll={(e)=>{
             scrollY.setValue(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y)
           }}
         contentContainerstyle={{flexGrow:1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", backgroundColor: "transparent",}}>
          
         <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent:"center", alignItems: "center",  }}>
             <Image source={require('../assets/trailer.png')} style={{width:250, height:90, top:7  }}/>
             <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{global.foo='zFMxkTeLP9M'; setModalVisible(true)}}>
             <Image source={require('../assets/showreel.jpeg')} style={{width:screenWidth*0.93, borderRadius:10, top:-5, borderWidth:2, borderWidthColor:"green", height:200}} />
             </TouchableOpacity>
             <View style={{width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight*0.4, marginTop:10 }}>
              <View style={{width:'100%', flexDirection:"row", justifyContent:"space-between"}}>
                <Pressable onPress={()=>setShows('English')} style={{width:"50%", backgroundColor:setShowColorEnglish(), height:40, justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center",}}>
                  <Image source={require('../assets/HS.png')} style={{width:'90%', height:screenHeight*0.086, top:1.7}} />
                </Pressable>
                <Pressable onPress={()=>setShows('Hindi')} style={{width:"50%", backgroundColor:setShowColorHindi(), height:40, justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center",}}>
                  <Image source={require('../assets/ES.png')} style={{width:'90%', height:screenHeight*0.086, top:1.7}} />
                </Pressable>
              </View>
               {shows == 'English' ? <TopShows api={api} /> : <HindiTopShows api ={hindiApi} /> }
             </View>
             <Image style={{width:276, height:56, marginBottom:10}} source={require('../assets/MorevideoTop.png')}/>
             <GlobalPlaylistCarousel onChange={value => setModalVisible(value)} api = {api.mostViewed} />
             <Image style={{width:200, height:56, marginVertical:10}} source={require('../assets/MoralStoryTop.png')}/>
             <GlobalPlaylistCarousel onChange={value => setModalVisible(value)} api={api.moralSorty}/>
             <Image style={{width:260, height:56, marginVertical:10}} source={require('../assets/TenaliRamanStoriesTop.png')}/>
             <GlobalPlaylistCarousel onChange={value => setModalVisible(value)} api={api.tenaliRamanStory}/>
             <Image style={{width:218, height:56, marginVertical:10}} source={require('../assets/nurseryRhymesTop.png')}/>
             <GlobalPlaylistCarousel onChange={value => setModalVisible(value)} api={api.nurseryRhymes}/>
             <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:"row",  width:screenWidth*0.8, justifyContent: "space-between", top:15,}}>
               <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>{ Linking.openURL(facebook)}}><Image style={{width:70, height:50, }} source={require('../assets/facebook.png')}/></TouchableOpacity>
               <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>{ Linking.openURL(youtubeUrl)}}><Image style={{width:70, height:50, }} source={require('../assets/youtube.png')}/></TouchableOpacity>
               <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>{ Linking.openURL(instagram)}}><Image style={{width:70, height:50, }} source={require('../assets/instagram.png')}/></TouchableOpacity>
             </View>
             <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={() =>{ Linking.openURL(subscribe)}}><Image style={{width:screenWidth, height:85, marginBottom:40}} source={require('../assets/subscribe.png')} onPress={() => Linking.openURL(subscribe)}/></TouchableNativeFeedback>
           </View>
         </Animated.ScrollView>
       </SafeAreaView>
        <Animated.View style={{ flex: 1, position: "absolute", width: "100%", bottom: 0, backgroundColor: 'rgba(58, 58, 58, 0.8)', zIndex:1000, elevation:1000, transform:[{translateY:footerY}] }}>
            <FooterTabs />
        </Animated.View>
        </>
    )
}

export default Home
```

This the code of other screen from where I'm getting the error:

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {Image, TouchableOpacity, BackHandler, Animated, ImageBackground, SafeAreaView, StatusBar, Text, View, TextInput, ScrollView, Linking, Dimensions, Modal, Alert} from "react-native";
import FooterTabs from "../component/Nav/FooterTabs";
import AudioHandler from "../component/SongModules/Audio";
import IconA from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { useFonts, Coiny_400Regular } from '@expo-google-fonts/coiny'
import { playSound } from "../component/sound";

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');
const HeaderHeight = height*0.075


const Listen = (navigation) => {
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Coiny_400Regular
  });
  const scrollY = new Animated.Value(0)
    const diffClampScrollY = Animated.diffClamp(scrollY, 0, HeaderHeight+StatusBar.currentHeight)
    const headerY = diffClampScrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange:[0, HeaderHeight],
      outputRange: [0, -HeaderHeight]
    })
    const footerY = diffClampScrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange:[0, HeaderHeight],
      outputRange: [0, HeaderHeight]
    })

  return (
    <>
      <ImageBackground source={require('../assets/bg.png')}  style={{width:"100%", height: "100%",
        position: "absolute", top:0, left:0, right: 0, bottom:0,
      }}/>
        <SafeAreaView >
          <Animated.View style={{width:width, height:height*0.075, backgroundColor:'rgba(29, 11, 3, 0.75)', position:"absolute", justifyContent:"center", zIndex:1000, elevation:1000, transform:[{translateY:headerY}]}}>
          <View style={{width:width*0.7, height:height*0.05, marginLeft:width*0.025, justifyContent:"space-between", alignItems:"center", flexDirection:"row", }}>
            <IconA name="chevron-back-circle-sharp" size={30} color="yellow" onPress={()=>{playSound() ;navigation.navigation.goBack('Home')}} />
            <Text style={{fontWeight:"bold", color:"#fff", fontSize:18}}>Bloomtelly Podcast</Text>
          </View>
          </Animated.View>
          <Animated.ScrollView 
          bounces={false}
          scrollEventThrottle={16}
          style={{paddingTop:HeaderHeight}}
            onScroll={(e)=>{
              scrollY.setValue(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y)
            }}
          >
          <View contentContainerstyle={{flexGrow:1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", backgroundColor: "transparent",}}>
              <AudioHandler navigation={navigation}/>
              <Image source={require("../assets/space.png")} style={{height:65}}/>
          </View>
          </Animated.ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
        <Animated.View style={{flex:1, position:"absolute", width:"100%", bottom:0, backgroundColor: 'rgba(29, 11, 3, 0.75)', zIndex:1000, elevation:1000, transform:[{translateY:footerY}] }}>
          <FooterTabs />
        </Animated.View>
      </>
  )
};


export default Listen;
```

Comment: there is no way we can help you by just looking at those images, please put your code in the question description, or put it on <https://snack.expo.dev> and share the link

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have added the code and additionally I would like to mention that codes are similar in every pages, only navigating from the above mention page I'm having the error. Please have a look and provide me you suggestion.